# What is the safe way to fill multidimensional array using std::fill?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, fill

Here is what I am using:

```
class something
{
   char flags[26][80];
} a;

std::fill(&a.flags[0][0], &a.flags[0][0] + 26 * 80, 0);
```

(Update: I should have made it clear earlier that I am using this inside a class.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The simple way to initialize to `0` the array is in the definition:

```
char flags[26][80] = {};
```

If you want to use `std::fill`, or you want to *reset* the array, I find this a little better:

```
char flags[26][80];
std::fill( &flags[0][0], &flags[0][0] + sizeof(flags) /* / sizeof(flags[0][0]) */, 0 );
```

The `fill` expressed in terms of the array size will allow you to change the dimensions and keep the `fill` untouched. The `sizeof(flags[0][0])` is `1` in your case (`sizeof(char)==1`), but you might want to leave it there in case you want to change the type at any point.

In this particular case (array of *flags* --integral type) I could even consider using `memset` even if it is the least *safe* alternative (this will break if the array type is changed to a non-pod type):

```
memset( &flags[0][0], 0, sizeof(flags) );
```

Note that in all three cases, the array sizes are typed only once, and the compiler deduces the rest. That is *a little safer* as it leaves less room for programmer errors (change the size in one place, forget it in the others).

EDIT: You have updated the code, and as it is it won't compile as the array is private and you are trying to initialize it externally. Depending on whether your class is actually an aggregate (and want to keep it as such) or whether you want to add a constructor to the class you can use different approaches.

```
const std::size_t rows = 26;
const std::size_t cols = 80;
struct Aggregate {
   char array[rows][cols];
};
class Constructor {
public:
   Constructor() {
      std::fill( &array[0][0], &array[rows][0], 0 ); // [1]
      // memset( array, 0, sizeof(array) );
   }
private:
   char array[rows][cols];
};
int main() {
   Aggregate a = {};
   Constructor b;
}
```

Even if the `array` is meant to be public, using a constructor might be a better approach as it will guarantee that the `array` is properly initialized in all instances of the class, while the external initialization depends on user code not forgetting to set the initial values.

[1] As @Oli Charlesworth mentioned in a comment, using constants is a different solution to the problem of having to state (and keep in synch) the sizes in more than one place. I have used that approach here with a yet different combination: a pointer to the first byte outside of the bidimensional array can be obtained by requesting the address of the first column one row beyond the bidimensional array. I have used this approach just to show that it can be done, but it is not any better than others like `&array[0][0]+(rows*cols)`

Comment: +1.  However, an alternative to using `sizeof` is to `#define` (or `const int`) the dimensions.  This has the added advantage that it will work if you've passed `flags` as a function argument, so that it's decayed to a pointer so `sizeof` will no longer give the correct result.

Comment: I'm not sure I can use the initializing braces because the 2d array is inside a class. I'll give you a chance to update before I accept.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez: Can you explain why a similar syntax i.e. `fill(&arr[0], &arr[0] + sizeof(arr), 0) ` doesn't work for a 1D array?

Comment: @DhruvMullick: The `sizeof` operator gives you the size in bytes, not the number of elements, if `arr` holds anything such that `sizeof(*arr) != 1` the above has undefined behavior and will probably crash (try to access well beyond the end of the array). Otherwise (i.e. if the array holds `[unsigned|signed] char`, it should be working

Comment: Actually I didn't know that in the syntax for fill, we use the number of elements.

Comment: @DhruvMullick: you can use cppreference to check the documentation for the standard library components. `fill` does **not** take the number of elements, it takes two *iterators*, to obtain the second iterator you need to do some arithmetic, but that is always in terms of *elements* not bytes.

Comment: quite old answer, however, shouldnt it be `&array[rows][cols]` as the second argument to `fill` ?

Comment: @tobi303: I don't think so. `&array[rows][cols]` is one whole row beyond the last element in the array, not just one element past.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I just realized how stupid I am ;) of course your version is right and I was just a bit confused

Comment: I like this answer, and I agree that it's likely to work on any real system.  But is it _guaranteed_ to work?  It seems to me that `flags[0][0]` is an element of the 80-dimension array `flags[0]`, hence `&flags[0]0]` is a pointer into that array, whereas `&flags[0][0] + sizeof(flags)` yields a pointer that is (more than one element) past the end of that array.  What in the standard explicitly allows such arithmetic here?  And what allows `std::fill` to take `iterator`s to different containers (`flags[0]` and `flags[25]`)?

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: The standard guarantees that you can obtain (but not dereference) a pointer one beyond any array. Furthermore, there is a clause that allows using a single object, for the purpose of pointer arithmetic, as if it was an array of a single element for the purpose of obtaining a pointer one beyond the object.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez, are you saying that `&flags[0][0]` returns a pointer to an object that can be considered an element of an array of 26 * 80 elements and that pointer arithmetic can be taken "with respect to" this big, 1-dimensional array?  I can believe that, but I'd be _very_ interesting in seeing the clause that spells this out.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues, I don't believe what we need here is covered by the cases mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: I misunderstood your question as relating to the access one beyond the end of an array, which is what those clauses guarantee. On the question you now have, there are no bidimensional arrays in C++. The different rules dealing with pointer arithmetic on the outer and inner arrays indirectly guarantee that the above is valid. The size of an array of N elements is N times the size of the element (no external padding) That guarantees that the first element in the second inner array is located at the address of one beyond the last element in the first.

Comment: ... if you apply the same reasoning to the last element in the outer array you end up with the address of one beyond the last inner array being exactly the same as the address of one beyond the last outer array.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I still don't see why I'm allowed to start with an element of an 80-long array (`flags[0][0]`, an element of `flags[0]`), take its address (`&flags[0][0]`), and then add 2080 (`(sizeof flags)/(sizeof flags[0][0])`) to it.

Comment: @Joshua: `&flags[0] + 25` is a pointer to the beginning of the last innner array of 80 characters, right? And it is 2000 chars into the array. Given the last inner array of 80 characters, `char (&last)[80] = flags[25]`, you can obtain a pointer one beyond the end of this one array by offsetting by `sizeof last / sizeof *last`, that is, 80 characters or a total of 2080 characters. You can do the math this long way, or you can do it the short way

Comment: It is the "and it is 2000 characters into the array" part that I'm not sure of.  Yes, _if_ you're allowed to treat `flags` as one big `char` array of length 26 * 80, _then_ everything works.  Alas, you haven't defined such an array.  Rather, you've defined an array of arrays, and arithmetic is taking you from one small array into another.  Such array arithmetic normally yields undefined behavior, e.g., `char a[10]; char b[10]; char *p = a + 11;` is undefined even if `a` and `b` are consecutive in memory.  I can _believe_ the arithmetic is OK for `flags`, but what in the standard guarantees it?

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: The standard guarantees that an array of N elements of type T takes `sizeof(T) * N` bytes, and it also guarantees that the each element is `sizeof(T)` bytes beyond the previous element. In this case the type `T` is `char[80]`. This is fundamental and the basis for pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The above arithmetic isn't staying inside one array.  `flags[0][0]` is an element of the 80-element array `flags[0]` but `&flags[0][0] + sizeof(flags)` takes us well outside of `flags[0]`.  Yes, it would be natural for this to take us into/through the other arrays in `flags` (`flags[1]`, `flags[2]`, `flags[3]`, etc.) and yes, the standard guarantees the memory layout makes this _sensible_, but I still don't see what guarantees that this arithmetic is _valid_ when arithmetic taking you outside your starting array normally yields undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: *taking you outside your starting array* The key word here is not *starting* array, but *complete object*. I am not sure how else to put it out... do the math working only on the outer array (which is guaranteed) up until the last inner array, then use pointer arithmetic on that array to jump to one past the end. A pointer so obtained is kosher and it is exactly `sizeof flags` bytes beyond `&flags[0][0]`. The operation is allowed **because** all that pointer arithmetic is done within a single *complete object*.

Comment: @dribeas, I'm not finding any clear quotes.  On StackOverflow I found "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."  `&flags[0][0]` points to an element of `flags[0]` while `&flags[0][0] + sizeof flags` does _not_ point to an element of (or one past the last element of) `flags[0]`.  _Maybe_ `flags[0][0]` can be considered an element of the array `flags`, but neither the definition nor the notation clearly support that.

Comment: @dribeas, to gain a better understanding of my concerns, consider what would happen if we instead defined `std::array<char, 80> flags[26];`.  Would the arithmetic be well-defined here?  I think the answer is "No" and I don't see why the case `char flags[26][80];` must _clearly_ be different, though it might very well be handled specially in the standard.

Comment: FWIW, the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290956/one-dimensional-access-to-a-multidimensional-array-well-defined-c) seems to suggest that the arithmetic _might_ be well-defined but _only because the data type is_ `char`.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: the discussion would be slightly more involved, since I have omitted `sizeof(T)` everywhere (knowing that it is 1 for `char`). But the arithmetic is sound regardless of the type

Comment: @dribeas, the discussion there seems to differ.  One argument is that treating the array of arrays of `T` as a single array of `T` violates the strict-aliasing rule (for which there's a special exception for `T == (unsigned) char`).  I'm personally not convinced that that's the _only_ problem with the arithmetic -- other parts of the standard seem to be rather strict as well -- but it appears to be at least one issue that must be considered.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: I find that a lack of understanding. `a[n]` is not reading the array as an array of one dimension, the `[]` operator has nothing to do with the type from which the pointer was obtained and is strictly a different representation of `*(a+n)`. There is *no* aliasing here at all. The user obtained a pointer to an element (exact type) and uses pointer arithmetic to reach other objects of the same type, not a different type that aliases the original.

Comment: @dribeas, the standard labels stepping (far enough) outside an array undefined behavior.  I worry that an implementation _could_ keep track of the valid range of any pointer (based on the array it came from) and penalize violations of this restriction.  Above, the compiler _could_ note that `flags[0][0]` is an element of `flags[0]` which contains 80 elements, hence it could penalize you for stepping further than that.  I doubt any real implementation does this, and gcc apparently guarantees not to, but why couldn't some other implementation work this way?

Comment: @dribeas, I can believe that you're right, that multidimensional arrays are treated specially in this regard.  (I don't think an array of `std::array`s could be flattened in this manner.)  However, I have yet to find a quote from the standard that justifies this belief.

Comment: what about a 3 dimensional array?

Comment: @akashchandrakar I know, I am a bit late. Still... I have found this post only talks about the specific issue in the OP's code rather having a generalized answer for the Question actually asked (i.e. *"What is the safe way to fill multidimensional array using `std::fill`?"*). Therefore added a new answer, which also solves for [*3-d array* fill cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948290/what-is-the-safe-way-to-fill-multidimensional-array-using-stdfill/63315283#63315283)

Answer (score 5):

> **What is the safe way to fill multidimensional array using `std::fill`**?

The easy default initialization would be [using braced inilization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization#Initialization_from_brace-enclosed_lists).

```
char flags[26][80]{};
```

The above will initialize all the elements in the `flags` to default char.

---

### 2-D Array filling using `std::fill` or `std::fill_n`

However, in order to provide different value to initialize the above is not enough. The options are [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n). (Assuming that the array `flags` is `public` in your class)

```
std::fill(
   &a.flags[0][0],
   &a.flags[0][0] + sizeof(a.flags) / sizeof(a.flags[0][0]),
   '0');

// or using `std::fill_n`
// std::fill_n(&a.flags[0][0], sizeof(a.flags) / sizeof(a.flags[0][0]), '1');
```

To generalize this for any *2d-array* of any type with any initializing value, I would suggest [a templated function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) as follows. This will also avoid the `sizeof` calculation of the total elements in the array.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::fill_n, std::fill
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t

template<typename Type, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
constexpr void fill_2D_array(Type(&arr2D)[M][N], const Type val = Type{}) noexcept
{
   std::fill_n(&arr2D[0][0], M * N, val);
   // or using std::fill
   // std::fill(&arr2D[0][0], &arr2D[0][0] + (M * N ), val);
}
```

Now you can initialize your `flags` like

```
fill_2D_array(a.flags, '0'); // flags should be `public` in your class!
```

**([See Live Online](https://godbolt.org/z/b7v45c))**

---

### 3-D Array filling using `std::fill` or `std::fill_n`

Adding one more non-template size parameter to the above template function, this can be brought to *3d-array*s as well

```
#include <algorithm> // std::fill_n
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t

template<typename Type, std::size_t M, std::size_t N, std::size_t O>
constexpr void fill_3D_array(Type(&arr3D)[M][N][O], const Type val = Type{}) noexcept
{
   std::fill_n(&arr3D[0][0][0], M * N * O, val);
}
```

**([See Live Online](https://godbolt.org/z/1v58qP))**

Answer (score 2):

it is safe, a two-dimensional array is an array of arrays. Since an array occupied contiguous storage, so the whole multidimensional thing will too. So yeah, it's OK, safe and portable. Assuming you are NOT asking about style, which is covered by other answers (since you're using flags, I strongly recommend `std::vector<std::bitset<80> > myFlags(26)`)

Comment: Are you certain the bitset would be suitable? I'm just storing either zero or one inside each space in he 2d array. These flags are used to track which positions on the console have been updated with my floodfill routine.

Comment: @Truncheon: you store 8 values in a char, right? And in order to get, say, 7th value in the 6th char you must do some bit shifting/anding etc. The bitset will do it for you. That is, it will store each flag in a bit, and you can set/unset each flag by its index without worrying about bit patterns. The only downside is that the bitset's size must be a compile-time constant. If you are familiar with boost, they have dynamic_bitset which is pretty much what its name is.

Comment: I believe that he is storing a single bit in each byte. That means that using a bitset of 26*80 positions and the appropriate `(row,col)->index` algebra the use of a single `bitset` will be more efficient in memory consumption.

Comment: @David: It will definitely be more efficient in terms of memory, but readability will suffer, that is he will have to write btst[numCols*row+col] which is less readable compared to v[row][col]. The decision is up to the OP and is dependent on his priorities.

Answer (score 1):

```
char flags[26][80];
std::fill((char*)flags, (char*)flags + sizeof(flags)/sizeof(char), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `char[80]` supposed to be a substitute for a real string type? In that case, I recommend the following:

```
std::vector<std::string> flags(26);
flags[0] = "hello";
flags[1] = "beautiful";
flags[2] = "world";
// ...
```

Or, if you have a C++ compiler that supports initialization lists, for example a recent g++ compiler:

```
std::vector<std::string> flags { "hello", "beautiful", "world" /* ... */ };
```

Comment: This doesn't try to answer the question, just gives advice that nobody asked for.