# Why is flattening a multidimensional array in C illegal?

Tags: c

My book (Pointers on C by Kenneth Reek) says that the following is *illegal* although it works fine.

```
  int arr[5][5];
  int *p=&arr[2][2];
  p=p+3; // As array is stored in row major form I think this 
         //should make p point to arr[3][0]
```

The book says leaving one row to the next row is illegal. But I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gelled on this for awhile, and I'll try my best to explain where I *think* he's coming from, though  without reading the book, it will be at-best-conjecture.

First, technically, the increment you propose (or he proposed) isn't illegal; *dereferencing* it is. The standard allows you to advance a pointer to one-past the last element of the array sequence from which it is being sourced for valuation, but not for dereference. Change it to `p = p + 4` and *both* are illegal.

That aside, the linear footprint of the array not withstanding, `ar[2]` has a type, and it is  `int[5]`. If you don't believe that, consider the following, all of which is correctly typed:

```
int ar[5][5];
int (*sub)[5] = ar+2;   // sub points to 3rd row
int *col = *sub + 2;    // col points to 3rd column of third row.
int *p = col + 3;       // p points to 5th colum of third row.
```

Whether this lands on `ar[3][0]` isn't relevant You're exceeding the declared magnitude of the dimension participating in the pointer-math. The result cannot legally be dereferenced, and were it larger than a 3-offset, nor could it be even legally evaluated.

Remember, the array being addressed is `ar[2]`; not just `ar`, and said-same is declared to be size=5. That it is buttressed up against two other arrays of the same ilk isn't relevant to the addressing *currently* being done. I believe [Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6291590/1322972) to the question proposed as a duplicate should have been the one selected for outright-solution. In particular, the reference to **C99 §6.5.6, p8** which, though wordy, appears below with:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
>   In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
>   array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
>   (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
>   i−n-th elements of the array object, **provided they exist**. Moreover, if
>   the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.** If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
>   operator that is evaluated.

Sorry for the spam, but the bolded highlights are what I believe is relevant to your question. By addressing as you are, *you're leaving the array being addressed*, and as such walking into UB. in short, it works (usually), but is isn't legal.

Answer (score 7):

The reason that the book says it's illegal is because pointer arithmetic is guaranteed to work only on pointers to elements in the same array, or one past the end.

`arr` is an array of 5 elements, in which each element is an array of 5 integers. Thus, theoretically, if you want to have pointers to array elements in `arr[i]`, you can only do pointer arithmetic that yields pointers in the range `&arr[i][0..4]` or `arr[i]+5` **keeping `i` constant**.

For example, imagine `arr` was a one dimensional of 5 integers. Then a pointer `p` could only point to each of `&arr[0..4]` or `arr+5` (one past the end). This is what happens with multi-dimensional arrays as well.

With `int arr[5][5];`, you can only do pointer arithmetic such that you always have a pointer that is in the range `&arr[i][0..4]` or `arr[i]+5` - that's what the rules say. It just may be confusing because these are arrays inside arrays, but the rule is the same no matter what. Conceptually, `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are different arrays, and even though you know they are contiguous in memory, it is illegal to do pointer arithmetic between elements of `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`. Remember that conceptually, each element in `arr[i]` is a different array.

In your example, however, `p+3` will point one past the end of `arr[2][2]`, so it looks to me like it is valid nonetheless. It's a poor choice of an example because it will make `p` point precisely to one past the end, making it still valid. Had the author chosen `p+4`, the example would be correct.

Either way, I have never had any problems with flattening multidimensional arrays in C using similar methods.

Also see this question, it has got other useful information: [One-dimensional access to a multidimensional array: well-defined C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290956/one-dimensional-access-to-a-multidimensional-array-well-defined-c)

Comment: Does C stardand allow gaps between the subarrays of `arr[5][5]`, for example, `arr[1][0]` does not follow `arr[0][4]` directly?

Comment: @leeduhem No, I don't think it allows. The C standard states that array elements are contiguous in memory, and that they are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest). See section 6.2.5.1., "Array subscripting". It follows from this that there can't be gaps in between.

Comment: It looks like this can guarantee defined behavior for expression like `*(p+4)`, because if `p = &arr[2][2]`, `p+4` always points to `arr[3][1]`.

Comment: @leeduhem No, it doesn't guarantee, because `p+4` goes out of bounds of the array it is pointing to. Yes, you know that after `arr[2]` there is another array, but even though it's contiguous, for whatever it's worth, it's **another** array, so you can't do that. This is a dark corner of C. Theoretically, it might not work, but I believe it always works. I guess it's just an inconsistency in the standard.

Comment: Agreed, this may just be an inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is illegal in C. In fact by doing so you are laying to your compiler. `p` is pointing to the element `arr[2][2]` (and is of pointer to `int` type), i.e, 3rd element of third row. The statement `p=p+3;` will increment the pointer `p` to `arr[2][5]`, which is equivalent to `arr[3][0]`.
But this will fail whenever memory is allocated as a power of `2` ( `2`<sup>`n`</sup> ) on some architechture. Now in this case the memory allocation would round up to  `2`<sup>`n`</sup>, i.e, in your case, each row would round up to `64` bytes.
See a test program in which the memory allocated is 5 allocations of 10 integers.  On some machines, memory allocations are a multiple of 16 bytes, so the 40 bytes requested is rounded up to 48 bytes per allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void print_numbers(int *num_ptr, int n, int m);
extern void print_numbers2(int **nums, int n, int m);

int main(void)
{
    int **nums;
    int n = 5;
    int m = 10;
    int count = 0;

    // Allocate rows
    nums = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    // Allocate columns for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
        printf("%2d: %p\n", i, (void *)nums[i]);
    }

    // Populate table
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            nums[i][j] = ++count;

    // Print table
    puts("print_numbers:");
    print_numbers(&nums[0][0], n, m);
    puts("print_numbers2:");
    print_numbers2(nums, n, m);
    return 0;
}

void print_numbers(int *nums_ptr, int n, int m)
{
    int (*nums)[m] = (int (*)[m])nums_ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d: %p\n", i, (void *)nums[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", nums[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void print_numbers2(int **nums, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d: %p\n", i, (void *)nums[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%3d", nums[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Sample output on Mac OS X 10.8.5; GCC 4.8.1:

```
 0: 0x7f83a0403a50
 1: 0x7f83a0403a80
 2: 0x7f83a0403ab0
 3: 0x7f83a0403ae0
 4: 0x7f83a0403b10
print_numbers:
 0: 0x7f83a0403a50
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 1: 0x7f83a0403a78
  0  0 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 2: 0x7f83a0403aa0
 19 20  0  0 21 22 23 24 25 26
 3: 0x7f83a0403ac8
 27 28 29 30  0  0 31 32 33 34
 4: 0x7f83a0403af0
 35 36 37 38 39 40  0  0 41 42
print_numbers2:
 0: 0x7f83a0403a50
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 1: 0x7f83a0403a80
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 2: 0x7f83a0403ab0
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 3: 0x7f83a0403ae0
 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 4: 0x7f83a0403b10
 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Sample output on Win7; GCC 4.8.1:

[image]

Comment: `p+3` points to the same element as `arr[3][0]`. Looks valid to me.

Comment: @WhozCraig; Yes. I agreed. You are right. In fact I should increment column rather than rows.

Comment: aren't array's assigned in contiguous memory, if so p+3 should make it  point to arr[2][5], as in the end compiler gets only memory adddress??

Comment: @downvoters; Edited my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Could you give some source about this 2^n memeory allocation?

Comment: @leeduhem; I do not have strong evidence about it :). But once I got stuck with some similar issue. I asked this question to my mentor and he replied with a test program which I am including in my answer.

Comment: I never down voted, and will drop my comment as the only thing it pointed out has been addressed.

Comment: Does C standard have any requirement about the layout of array such as `arr[5][5]`? Such as `arr[1][0]` must next to `arr[0][5]`?

Comment: @leeduhem; I am not sure about that. But treating 2D array as 1D is not a good practice.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting? If anything is wrong with this answer then please do let me know. I will remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: @leeduhem It does. Section 6.5.2.1, paragraph 3 of C99: "[...] It follows from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest)" together with 6.2.5 entry 20: "[...] An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects."

Comment: Your test program is testing something completely different, thus adding to the confusion. A two-dimensional array is **not** the same as an array of pointers.

Comment: @user4815162342; I know. But the the issue is similar. No confusion here.

Comment: Not similar at all: you are confusing dynamic allocation with separate calls to `malloc` with the allocation of a contiguous (but multi-dimensional) array. Your test code is thus misleading and irrelevant to the question.