# I am having trouble passing a multidimensional variable array to a function in C using malloc()

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, multidimensional-array, malloc

this code should create an array in main and then print it but every time I run it I just get an array of all 0s

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(float **A, int w, int h){
  int i, j;

  A = (float*) malloc(w*h*sizeof(float));

  for (i=0;i<h;i++){
    A[i] = (float*) malloc(w*sizeof(float));
  }

  for (i=0; i<h; i++){
    for(j=0; j<w; j++){
      printf("%f ", A[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {

    int i;
    int x_dimension=3;
    int y_dimension=2;
    float arr [3][2]={};
    arr[0][0]=16.2;

    print(arr,x_dimension,y_dimension);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why bother allocating memory in `print()`? After all, you are just printing its content.

Comment: `float[M][N]` and `float**` are *not* the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-allocing it in your `print` function, this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(float * A,int h, int w){
  int i,j;
  for (i=0;i<h;i++){
    for(j=0;j<w;j++){
      printf("%f ",A[i * w + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    const int x_dimension=3;
    const int y_dimension=2;
    float arr[x_dimension][y_dimension];
    arr[0][0]=16.2;
    print(arr,x_dimension,y_dimension);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I also inverted the `w` and `h` parameters in the `print` function.

Comment: Why are you bending the rules, instead of doing the correct solution and fix the function parameters.

Comment: @self. what do you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143494/why-is-flattening-an-multidimensional-array-in-c-illegal

Comment: @jlhonora could you explain how your printf statement works, and was there any reason you changed the w and h around?

Answer (score 0):

I think you see the arr is not initialized:

1. alloc memory?
2. default values.
3. float arr[][] is not same with float **arr, you should use like this: `float (*A)[2]`

But in your main function, you have finished the *alloc* work. The *arr* is allocated at the stack.
So in your print function, what you have to do is only print the result or initialize each item's value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArr(float (*A)[2],int w, int h){
    int i,j;
    //Wrong, A has been alloced.
    /*
       A = (float*) malloc(w*h*sizeof(float));
       for (i=0;i<h;i++){
       A[i]=(float*) malloc(w*sizeof(float));
       }
       */
    for (i=0;i<h;i++){
        for(j=0;j<w;j++){
            printf("%f ",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printPointer(float *A,int w, int h){
    int i,j;
    //Wrong, A has been alloced.
    /*
       A = (float*) malloc(w*h*sizeof(float));
       for (i=0;i<h;i++){
       A[i]=(float*) malloc(w*sizeof(float));
       }
       */
    for (i=0;i<h;i++){
        for(j=0;j<w;j++){
            printf("%f ",*((A+i*h)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(void) {
    int x_dimension=3;
    int y_dimension=2;

    //By Array, Array is not a pointer, but is a structure
    float arr[2][3] = {};
    //Only [0][0] item has been initialized
    arr[0][0]=16.2f;
    printArr(arr,x_dimension,y_dimension);

    //By pointer
    float* arrp = (float*)calloc(x_dimension*y_dimension,sizeof(float));
    *arrp=16.2f;
    printPointer(arrp,x_dimension,y_dimension);


    return 0;
}
```