# How to define matrix dynamically in C

Tags: c, matrix, allocation

I created a program that prints 2 dimension matrix from external txt file. My program works if I define static matrix such as A[10][10]. But I want to allocate memory dynamically.

When I try this code:

```
int **A = (int **)malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
```

There is error as following:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00AC159B in dataStructures4.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.

On this loop:

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
        A[i][j] = -1;
    }
}
```

I think I can't generate dynamic matrix correctly. How should I modify my code?

Comment: A pointer to a pointer is not the same as an array of ints.

Comment: I think this question is similiar with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186294/i-am-having-trouble-passing-a-multidimensional-variable-array-to-a-function-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186294/i-am-having-trouble-passing-a-multidimensional-variable-array-to-a-function-in-c), you can see it. Array is more likely the struct. So if you want to access them, you should see the second dimension to a structure: `int *A[10]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dynamically create 2d arrays as a pointer to chunk of `int*` pointers which point to a chunk of `int`s.

So there are two steps:

1) `A` to point to the first of a chunk of `int*`

```
int **A = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
```

2) each of them to point to the first of a chunk of `int`s

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    A[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a pointer to an array of specific size:

You can use #define to define N, or use a variable:

```
int n = 10 ;
int (*A)[n] = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
```

This way you get a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: Too bad that `N` in `int (*A)[N]` must be known at compile time. This is not what he wants.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves No, you are wrong. You can do than no problem ( at least from c99 forward ). My proof( don't have time to search specs ) http://ideone.com/bW4Qeo

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Nice answer. I know C99 allows VLAs, I just wasn't thinking. +1

Comment: Ok then, but why wouldn't he use a 2D VLA in the first place?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves My answer does not have VLAs; maybe compiler doesn't support them or the array is too large for stack.

Comment: There is error as following; "IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value". So, if I use constant value how it could be dynamic memory allocated array?

Comment: @Mr.White because you allocated it dynamically. What compiler do you have? I'm guessing its VisualStudio, which doesn't support c99.

Comment: @self. Your answer surely makes use of VLAs. `A` is a pointer to a variable length array. If the compiler doesn't support VLAs, which seems to be the case, this won't work.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Ok, my bad, you need c99 or better.

Comment: @self. We both got confused for a while :p But it's a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: @self. Yes, my compiler is Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Technically your still wrong because I don't use VLAs; but only a pointer to a VLA. :-) You still need c99 though.

Comment: @Mr.White That is primarily a c++ compiler. You will have to define your values with a #define, or get a better c compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `A[i][j]` is the same as `*(*(A+i)+j)`. Your code is broken because `*(A+i)` dereferences an invalid, uninitialized pointer. This happens on this line:

```
A[i][j] = -1;
```

The alternative is to use a dynamically allocated array of pointers, where each element points to another dynamically allocated array. You can do it like this:

```
int **array = malloc(N*sizeof(*array));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    array[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(*array[i]));

/* Use array[i][j]... */
```

Note that the memory layout is very different from that of a 2D array, but the expression `array[i][j]` will do what you want - it will "look" like you have a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate each row separately, like here:

```
int **A = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));

for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    A[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as an array, a 2 dimension matrix holds a contiguous address space. So theoretically there is a way to achieve this.

```
int m = 2;
int n = 4;
int *a = malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));
int **b = malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
for(int i=0, i<m, i++)
{
    b[i] = a+i*n;
}
```

In this manner, b can be used as a matrix as you demand. However, it will waste malloc(m*sizeof(int*)) to hold b.

or you can:

```
int m = 2;
int n = 4;
int *a = malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));
```

use a[m*i+j] as a[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below stuff is good. I haven't tested it, just providing you with syntax.

```
int** abc; // Your 2D array pointer abc[N][M]

abc = (int**)malloc(dim1_max * sizeof(int*)); // dim1_max is N
for (int i = 0; i < dim1_max; i++) {
  abc[i] = (int*)malloc(dim2_max * sizeof(int)); // dim2_max is M
}

[....your array used....]
//Once you allocate dynamically you need to free the memory. IMP point.
for (int i = 0; i < dim1_max; i++) {
  free(abc[i]);
}
free(abc);
```