# convert two dimensional array to one dimensional in C

Tags: c, arrays, cuda

I have a two dimensional array like this:

```
ptr = (int **) malloc(size);

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ptr[i] = (int *) malloc(size);
}
```

Is there a simple way to create a `int *intPtr` to that array such that I can access the values in row major order?

e.g.: if `ptr` points to an n*n array, I want to get the first item of the second column like this: `*(intPtr + n)`

I need this conversion to pass my two dimensional array to a cuda kernel, I want to avoid to pass a two dimensional array to that kernel because that seems to be quiet complicated.

Comment: flatten your 2D array into a 1D array.  That's not hard to do since your dimension (`size`) is constant.  Then pass the 1D array to cuda, which is easy to do.  You can use subscript arithmetic on the 1D array to reference the 2D array elements if you want.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? In row-major ordering, `*(ptr + n)` is a pointer to the first element of the second row.  Did you mean that you want to "view" the array as if it were column-major, and have a pointer to the first element of the second column, which can be incremented to get other elements in the column?

Comment: When you say "the first item of the second column" do you mean just a single int, or do you mean a pointer via which you can access many ints, starting with the first?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally wrote "first item of the second column" but I actually meant the first item of the second row.

Answer (score 3):

No.  if you had allocated a true 2d array of `int`s:

```
int a[size][size];
```

then the answer might be yes though the result is not portable.  Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290956/one-dimensional-access-to-a-multidimensional-array-well-defined-c) for more array type punning information.

But accessing an element in a row of your array requires explicitly dereferencing a pointer.