# How to use pointer type in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am recently studying pointers and arrays. 
Suppose I initialize an array like

```
 int a[4]={6,2,3,4};
```

Now after reading a lot ,I understand that

1) `a` and `&a` will point to same location.But they aren't pointing to the same type.

2) `a` points to the first element of the array which is an integer value so the type of a is `int*`.

3) `&a` points to an entire array(i.e an integer array of size 4) therefore the type is `int (*)[]`.

Now what I actually don't get is how to use these type??

For Example:
CODE 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int (*arr)[4],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",*(*arr+i));
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int arr[4]={6,2,3,4};
    foo(&arr,4);
    return 0;
}
```

CODE 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",*(arr+i));
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int arr[4]={6,2,3,4};
    foo(&arr,4);
    return 0;
}
```

In code 2 we are passing &arr so its type should be of int (*)[],then how come we are getting the correct output even though we are having a type int *.

I really don't understand what is the meaning of type and how to use it?

Kindly explain with some examples.

Comment: type of `&a` is `int (*)[4]`, not `int (*)[]`

Comment: I bet your compiler will give you a warning with Code 2, something about incompatible pointer types...

Comment: You might want to see this question (I posted) and the answer on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851470/cast-t-to-t . Although your question has more than it. Since it tries to convert the pointer without a cast. Your compiler would at the least warn.

Comment: Code 2 is illegal code, your compiler permits it in the default mode because otherwise people whose programs rely on this sort of illegal code would get annoyed. IMO it is a good idea to configure the compiler to report errors

Comment: I am surprised code 2 gives that output. Suspect undefined behavior but need someone to reference backup

Comment: @texasbruce it "works" because in most implementations, dereference of a `int (*)[]` is a `NOP`.

Comment: Case 2 `foo (&arr, 4);` -> `foo (arr, 4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code 2 is not valid C, because a conversion between an array pointer and a pointer to `int` is not a valid pointer conversion - they are not compatible types. If it works, it is because of some non-standard extension of your compiler, or possibly you just "got lucky".

Please note that the best way to pass an array to a function in modern C is this:

```
void foo(int n, int arr[n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

As part of a function parameter list, `arr` will get adjusted to a pointer to the first element of the array, type `int*`.

The pedantically correct version would also replace `int n` and `int i` with `size_t`, which is the most proper type to use when describing the size of an object.

Comment: What's the upside of using this over the usual `void foo(int arr[], int n)`?

Comment: @a3f The advantage is that good compilers or static analysers may spot a type inconsistency when you try to pass anything but an array of size `n` to the function. In fact if you would have used array pointers like in the first example, you would be guaranteed by the standard to always get a compiler message if passing an array of wrong size. You also get self-documenting code - it is obvious to anyone viewing the function that the purpose of `n` is to express the array size.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass arrays in to functions is a pointer and the number of elements.

Note you can pass `arr` in to the function as `arr` or `&arr[0]`; both resolve to the same address.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int arr[4]={6,2,3,4};
    foo(arr,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, it's better to index the array, rather than addition and dereference. e.g. `*(arr+i)` becomes `arr[i]`.