# How to understand the syntax of C multidimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

My intuition when I see this `int array_name[x][y];` is an array of `y` arrays i.e. `array_name[x]` is one element out of `y` such elements. But turns out it's not so [in fact it's the opposite(?) ]

The guides/tutorials seem hellbent on bring matrices to explain this which makes it specific to 2D arrays. I'm looking to understand a general `array_name[w][x] ... [n]` syntax.

Note: fine, syntax is syntax, and this is how C defines it, okay. Then, is it true that `array_name[w][x] ... [n]` is simply an array of `w` elements each of which is `array_name[x] ... [n]`? But even this is not entirely correct because `int a[][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};` is valid even though the RHS contains a number of elements not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to read a multidimensional array declaration like

```
int arr[N][M];
```

is as an N-element array of M-element arrays of `int`.  Each `arr[i]` has type `int [M]`.

We can get there using substitution.  Let's start with a simple object declaration:

```
T a;
```

`a` is an instance of *something* which we call `T`.  Now replace `T` with the array type `R [N]`:

```
R a[N];
```

Important thing to note - since the `[]` operator is postfix in both expressions and declarations, when we substitute `T` with `R [N]` the `[N]` goes to the *rightmost* side of the declarator `a`, giving us `R a[N]`; the importance of this will be clear on the next round of substitution.

So now `a` is an N-element array of *something*, and that *something* is type `R`.  Now we replace `R` with another array type, `int [M]`:

```
int a[N][M];
```

Again, since the `[]` operator is postfix, we need to add it to the rightmost side of the declarator `a[N]` when doing the substitution, giving us `a[N][M]`.  `a` is still an N-element array of *something*, it's just now that something is "M-element array of `int`".  Hence, `a` is an N-element array of M-element arrays of `int`.

> But even this is not entirely correct because int a[][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; is valid even though the RHS contains a number of elements not divisible by 3.

That's covered here:

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> ...
> 21    If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
> of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
> size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

So that initializer is interpreted as:

```
int a[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,0,0}};
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int x[5][3];
```

declares `x` as an array with 5 elements. Each of these elements is an array with 3 `int`. You're correct so far.

But you should compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. Look here:

```
k.c:2:16: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
    2 |   int a[][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
      |                ^
      |                 {    }{    }{}
```

It's valid to initialize it this way, but the more proper way of initializing it is:

```
int a[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,0,0}};
```

This is much more readable. The zeros are not needed. If you initialize one single element, all other elements will be zeroed.

One more thing is that you can go out of bounds without actually going out of bounds with multi dimensional arrays. DO NOTE THAT EVEN IF THIS IS LIKELY TO WORK, IT'S UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, SO DON'T DO IT!

```
a[1][4] = (*a+1)[4]=*(*a+1)+4)
```

This is because `[]` is simply syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. So if you have declared `T x[5][3];` for some type `T`, then `x[1][1]` will point to the same element as `x[0][4]`

But as I said, it's UB. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62249658/6699433)

Comment: ... except that `x[0][4]` is UB: `x[0]` does not have index `4`. I guess only *DeathStar 9000* would misbehave with that though.

Comment: @pmg Are you 100% sure it's UB? I'm pretty sure it is not.

Comment: I meant [DeathStation 9000](http://web.archive.org/web/20110402085709/dialspace.dial.pipex.com/town/green/gfd34/art/)

Comment: `x[0][4]` is `*(*(x+0)+4)` by definition of the subscript operator. In this, `*(x+0)` is an array of three `int`, which is converted to a pointer to the first `int` of `x[0]`, which I will call `y`. Then the addition is specified by C 2018 6.5.6 8, which says the behavior is not defined if the pointer (`y`) and the result do not point to elements of the same array object or one past it. Since `y` points to an element in `x[0]` and `y+4` does not, and not one past, the behavior is not defined. The fact that they are both contained within a larger array is irrelevant to this passage in 6.5.6 8.