# how to access c 2d array with 1 index

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a[2][2] = { 0,1,2,3};
    printf("\n%d %d \n%d %d\n",a[0][0],a[0][1],a[1][0],a[1][1]);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",*a[0],*a[1],*a[2],*a[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

which returns:

```
0 1 
2 3
0 2 0 1491303602
```

Is there a way to access the 2d array with 1 index? Since the array is held in contiguous memory, shouldn't we be able to do this?

also:

```
printf("\n%d %d \n%d %d\n",&a[0][0],&a[0][1],&a[1][0],&a[1][1]);
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
```

produces the following:

```
1137924528 1137924532 
1137924536 1137924540
1137924528 1137924536 1137924544 1137924552
```

so why are the memory addresses of the first two elements &a[0][0] = a[0]
and &a[0][1] = a[1] but the last two don't match?

Comment: Related question: [One-dimensional access to a multidimensional array: is it well-defined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290956/12149471)

Comment: Related question: [Multidimensional array out of bound access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48219108/12149471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a[2][2] = { 0,1,2,3};
    printf("\n%d %d \n%d %d\n",a[0][0],a[0][1],a[1][0],a[1][1]);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",*a[0],*a[1],*a[2],*a[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

the line

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",*a[0],*a[1],*a[2],*a[3]);
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a[0][0],a[1][0],a[2][0],a[3][0]);
```

This means that you are accessing the object `a` out of bounds, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What you probably want to do is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a[2][2] = { {0,1}, {2,3} };
    int *p = &a[0][0];
    printf("%d %d \n%d %d\n",a[0][0], a[0][1], a[1][0],a[1][1]);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", p[0],p[1], p[2], p[3] );

    return 0;
}
```

Another way of writing this is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a[2][2] = { {0,1}, {2,3} };
    printf( "%d %d \n%d %d\n", a[0][0], a[0][1], a[1][0], a[1][1] );
    printf( "%d %d %d %d\n", a[0][0], a[0][1],a[0][2], a[0][3] );

    return 0;
}
```

These programs have the following output on my compiler:

```
0 1 
2 3
0 1 2 3
```

Although this will probably work on all compilers, it is worth noting that doing this may invoke undefined behavior, depending on how strictly you interpret the standard. This is because you are accessing the first sub-array `a[0]` out of bounds, but not the object `a` as a whole. See the following question for further information:

[One-dimensional access to a multidimensional array: is it well-defined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290956/12149471)

The compilers gcc and clang actually both provide a run-time warning for the second program, if I compile with `-fsanitize=undefined`. The compiler clang additionally provides a compile-time warning, if I enable all warnings.

For these reasons, it would probably be better to declare a 1D array instead of a 2D array, and to perform the index calculatings into the 1D array yourself, if you want to use the 1D array as a 2D array. That way, you can be sure that what you are doing is allowed by the ISO C standard. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 2
#define COLUMNS_PER_ROW 2

int calculate_1D_offset( int row, int column )
{
    return row * COLUMNS_PER_ROW + column;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[ROWS*COLUMNS_PER_ROW] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    //find the value of a[1][0], as if "a" were a 2D array
    printf( "%d\n", a[calculate_1D_offset(1,0)] );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
2
```

> so why are the memory addresses of the first two elements &a[0][0] = a[0] and &a[0][1] = a[1] but the last two don't match?

The array `a` consists of 2 sub-arrays, each consisting of 2 `int` elements. So the total number of `int` elements is 4.

In your question, the addresses are the following:

`1137924528` is the address of the element `a[0][0]`.
`1137924532` is the address of the element `a[0][1]`.
`1137924536` is the address of the element `a[1][0]`.
`1137924540` is the address of the element `a[1][1]`.

In your question, the line

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
```

has the following output:

```
1137924528 1137924536 1137924544 1137924552
```

The last two addresses are out of bounds, because the sub-arrays `a[2]` and `a[3]` do not exist. Only `a[0]` and `a[1]` exist.

If `a[2]` did exist, its address would be `1137924544`, which would be the the address of the 5<sup>th</sup> `int` element of the 2D array, i.e. `a[0][4]` (because indexes in C are 0-based).

However, I doubt that these addresses are actually correct, because you are using the wrong `printf` format specifier for printing an address. In order to print an address, you should use `%p` instead of `%d`, as `%d` is intended for an `int`, not a pointer. On platforms on which pointers are 64-bit and an `int` is 32-bit, the 32 [most significant bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Bit_significance_and_indexing) may be stripped off the value, or worse.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int a[2][2] = { 0,1,2,3};
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d\n",a[0][0],a[0][1],a[1][0],a[1][1]);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",*a[0],*(a[0] + 1), *a[1], *(a[1] + 1));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3avvnssn5

Result:

```
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets "draw" your array:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

From this it's easy to see a pattern emerging, telling us that we can use a single array to represent all two "dimensions":

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0]    | a[1]    | a[2]    | a[3]    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Now all we have to do is come up with a formula to calculate the one-array index from the matrix x,y pair.

In the first "row" we get the index by simply using the column index. For the second "row" we need to add the number of "columns".

So the generic calculation is `current_row * total_columns + current_column`.

I code it would look something like this:

```
const int total_rows = 2;
const int total_columns = 2;

char a[total_rows * total_columns] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

for (unsigned current_row = 0; current_row < total_rows; ++ total_rows)
{
    for (unsigned current_column = 0; current_column < total_columns; ++ total_columns)
    {
        printf("matrix[%d][%d] = %d\n", current_row, current_column,
               a[current_row * total_columns + current_column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Buy it does not access 2D array using the single index

Comment: you never declare a 2d array?  I down voted your answer as the code doesn't run. could you clarify?

Comment: @DCR I think I misunderstood the question. Then you can simply use a pointer to the first element, like `int *p = &a[0][0];`, and use e.g. `p[3]` to reference `a[1][1]`. One index to get values from a "2D" array. The "drawing" should  hopefully help you understand the mapping between pointer indexes and your array indexes.