# C: Why does assigning a 2D array of ints to an int** cause CLION to highlight the line?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, clion

This probably sounds like a previously asked question - there are a bunch of questions out there about the difference between arrays and pointers in C, but none of them provide quite enough information to answer this question.

I know that the name of a C array is treated by the C compiler like a pointer to the start of the memory block, but when I try to assign the name of a 3 x 3 2D array of ints to an `int **` in my CLION IDE, it highlights the assignment and says:

> Incompatible pointer types 'int * *' and 'int [3][3]'

```
int x[3][3];
int **px = x;  <-- warning here
```

I can cast the assigned value to (int**) and the highlight goes away of course, but - hey - you can cast a helluva lot of stuff in C and get highlights to go away. Doesn't mean what you're asking for is going to work.

Is this just a CLION (or, probably more appropriately, clang tidy) problem, or is a real issue?

[edit]

For some context, the problem with all the other answers on array/pointer differences is that many of them say things like "because an 3x3 array is not a int **, that's why!" Thanks, but that's a fairly useless piece of information - the person asking the question likely already knows a 3x3 array is not an int ** - the question is how does the compiler treat the resulting int ** after the assignment - will it properly index the array or not?

Comment: Could you post the line in question?

Comment: A 2d array is **not** an array of pointers, that's why.

Comment: An `int**` is a sequential list of `int*`; an `int[3][3]` is a sequential list of 3 sequential lists of 3 ints. `int[]` decays to `int*` by resolving to the address of the first element of the array, but that can't work transitively.

Comment: "or is a real issue?" Quite real. The message explains.

Comment: Nothing real in this bullshit warnings :)

Comment: assign it to the correct type of pointer (a pointer to a 3-element array of `int`) like e.g. `int array[3][3]; int (*x)[3] = array;`.

Comment: Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489359/2371524).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While someone can correct me on this one multidimensional array may not be and usually is not implemented as array of pointers, it's contiguous piece of memory with some syntaxic sugar on top of it for dereferencing.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565048/7034621) for details.

Comment: Thanks @orhtej2  - don't know how I missed that answer - it perfectly answers my question.

Comment: Yes, but that "syntactic sugar" makes it to be compatible with `int **`

Comment: @AntonMalyshev can I see how? The link I provided suggests otherwise.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev after reading the provided link, I now understand how an int ** cannot be used to properly reference an int array[3][3]. An int ** is a pointer to an array of pointers, while an int \*array[3] is a pointer to an array of 3-integer objects. Assuming a pointer is 8 bytes wide, and 3 integers are 3 x 4 or 12 bytes wide, it makes no sense to assume the compiler will properly index an int** pointer into the array of 3-int objects, even with a type cast.

Comment: A multidimensional array in fact can not ever be implemented as an array of pointers, it isn't optional, so we can do better than "usually is not". Each successive dimension must be implemented as a contiguous array of arrays.

Comment: @JohnCalcote: `int *array[3]` is actually an array of three elements of type pointer-to-`int`. `int (*array)[3]` would be a pointer to an array of three elements of type `int`.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev: The two are absolutely not compatible. Consider `int a[4][4] = {0};` This will give you, assuming 32-bit `int`s, a 64-byte block of memory with all bits set to zero. If you point `int ** p` at that, `p[0]` will be a null pointer, and `p[0][0]` will give you a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry for my erroneous comments!

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - thank you for that correction - you're absolutely correct - there have been a lot of comments around here lately that int *array[3] is just another notation for int array[][3].