# Can you multiply two 2d arrays like this in C?

Tags: c

I have two 2D arrays that look like this, `int A[3][3]` and `int B[3][3]`, and I have to multiply them. Can I do it like this? Make a function and just send them to it? I know I can but is this how you multiply 2D arrays?

```
void mult(int *C,int *A,int *B){
    for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
        *C = (*A) * (*B);
        C++;
        A++;
        B++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: This *might* be better on the Code Review SE.

Comment: Are you asking if this is valid according to the language, or if this is good style?

Comment: @kaylum "I know I can" suggests that he tried it and it worked. But lots of code with UB seems to work sometimes, so that's not a good test.

Comment: You might want to read up [Matrix Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) if that's what you're asking, as what you're doing isn't that.

Comment: if its good according to style cuz i saw that someone did it like this 
`
void mult(int *a,int *b,int *c){
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    *(c+i)=*(a)**(b+i)+*(a+1)**(b+i+3)+*(a+2)**(b+i+6);
}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    *(c+i+3)=*(a+3)**(b+i)+*(a+1+3)**(b+i+3)+*(a+2+3)**(b+i+6);
}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    *(c+i+6)=*(a+6)**(b+i)+*(a+1+6)**(b+i+3)+*(a+2+6)**(b+i+6);
}

}
`

Comment: You have an elementwise multiplication here which is not the same as matrix multiplication, if you are looking for it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes im looking for matrix mulitplication

Comment: Then the answer to your question is  -no, this is not how you multiply matrices.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can u direct me to somewhere where i can learn it,i get it how u do it in math but I cant wrap my head around how to do it in C

Comment: Just google "matrix muliplication in C" and you will get plenty of relevant results with ready-to-use codes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok thank you very much

Comment: Can I do it like this? --> it is OK as long as `C` does not overlap `A,B`.

Answer (score 2):

Elementwise multiplication done this way is OK. If you use indexes for some reason gcc does not want to emit vector code.

```
void mult(int C[3][3],int A[3][3],int B[3][3]){
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<3;j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j];
        }
}

void mult1(int *C,int *A,int *B){
    for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
        *C = (*A) * (*B);
        C++;
        A++;
        B++;
    }
}
```

but the code generated for this small arrays is different in both cases:

https://godbolt.org/z/Gr31Tf

Comment: And if int[3] is padded? (I really hope it's not but I'm not prepared to say for all architectures.)

Comment: @Joshua Arrays are not padded.

Comment: @Joshua structs & unions can be padded Arrays are not. IMO missed optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VLAs:

```
void mult(int r, int c, int C[r][c], int A[r][c], int B[r][c]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j];
}
...

int A[3][3], B[3][3], C[3][3];
mult(3, 3, C, A, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to be really clear what you mean here - do you mean you want to multiply each `a[i][j]` by each `b[i][j]` and assign the result to `c[i][j]`, such that

```
+---+---+   +---+---+   +-----+-----+     +----+----+
| 1 | 2 |   | 5 | 6 |   | 1*5 | 2*6 |     |  5 | 12 |
+---+---+ x +---+---+ = +-----+-----+  =  +----+----+
| 3 | 4 |   | 7 | 8 |   | 3*7 | 4*8 |     | 21 | 32 |
+---+---+   +---+---+   +-----+-----+     +----+----+
```

Or are you trying to implement *matrix multiplication* where

```
+---+---+   +---+---+   +-----------+-----------+   +----+----+
| 1 | 2 |   | 5 | 6 |   | 1*5 + 2*7 | 1*6 + 2*8 |   | 19 | 22 |
+---+---+ x +---+---+ = +-----------+-----------+ = +----+----+
| 3 | 4 |   | 7 | 8 |   | 3*5 + 4*7 | 3*6 + 4*8 |   | 43 | 50 |
+---+---+   +---+---+   +-----------+-----------+   +----+----+
```

which is *very* different?

If the former, then what you've written is mostly okay depending on how you're calling the function - remember that under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will "decay" to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  An expression of type "3-element array of 3-element array of `int`" (`int [3][3]`) will decay to type "pointer to *3-element array* of `int`", (`int (*)[3]`), *not* `int *`.

If you declare your arrays as

```
int a[3][3], b[3][3], c[3][3];
```

and call the function as

```
mult( &a[0][0], &b[0][0], &c[0][0] ); // explicitly pass a pointer to the
                                      // first element of each array
```

then what you have is fine. A little ugly, but fine.

If, OTOH, you're calling the function as

```
mult( a, b, c );
```

then what you have is ***not*** fine because the argument types don't match up (and the compiler *should* yell at you over it).  In order for the argument types to match up, your function prototype will need to be one of

```
void mult( int A[3][3], int B[3][3], int C[3][3] )
```

or

```
void mult( int A[][3], int B[][3], int C[][3] )
```

or

```
void mult( int (*A)[3], int (*B)[3], int (*C)[3] )
```

which all mean the same thing in the context of a function parameter declaration<sup>1</sup>.  But this also means you can't "walk" through the arrays just by incrementing and dereferencing the pointer, because you'd basically wind up iterating over `A[0][0]`, `A[1][0]`, and `A[2][0]`, *and* you'd get a type error because `*A` is not an `int`, it's an `int [3]`.  The actual meat of the code would need to be

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  for ( size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    C[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j];
```

When dealing with arrays, especially multi-dimensional arrays, use array subscript notation rather than trying to muck with pointers or pointer arithmetic - that's what it's there for, and you're less likely to make a mistake.

---

Matrix multiplication is a different matter - each `C[R][V]` is the sum of `A[R][x] * B[x][V]` for all `x`, and trying to do that with just pointer arithmetic is masochistic.  For that, you'd want to do something like:

```
for ( size_t R = 0; R < 2; R++ )
{
  for ( size_t V = 0; V < 2; V++ )
  {
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
      C[R][V] += A[R][i] * B[i][V]; // assumes C[R][V] has already been initialized to 0
    }
  }
}
```

For a general purpose matrix multiplication function, where you don't just have 3x3 matrices, something like this might work (assumes variable-length arrays are supported, which if you're working on a C99 or later implementation they should be):

```
void mat_mul_v( size_t ar, size_t ac, int a[ar][ac],
                size_t br, size_t bc, int b[br][bc],
                size_t cr, size_t cc, int c[cr][cc] )
{
  assert( ar == bc );  // number of rows in a must equal number of columns in b
  assert( ac == br );  // likewise, number of columns in a must equal number of rows in b
  assert( ar == cr );  // c must have the same number of rows as a
  assert( bc == cc );  // and the same number of columns as b

  memset( c, 0, sizeof *c * cr );

  for ( size_t R = 0; R < cr; R++ )
  {
    for ( size_t V = 0; V < cc; V++ )
    {
      for ( size_t i = 0; i < ac; i++ )
      {
        c[R][V] += a[R][i] * b[j][V];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Small test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void mat_mul_v( size_t ar, size_t ac, int a[ar][ac],
                size_t br, size_t bc, int b[br][bc],
                size_t cr, size_t cc, int c[cr][cc] )
{
  assert( ar == bc );
  assert( ac == br );
  assert( ar == cr );
  assert( bc == cc );

  memset( c, 0, sizeof *c * cr );

  for ( size_t R = 0; R < cr; R++ )
  {
    for ( size_t V = 0; V < cc; V++ )
    {
      for ( size_t i = 0; i < ac; i++ )
      {
        c[R][V] += a[R][i] * b[i][V];
      }
    }
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  int a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; // 1  2  3    1  2  3    30  36  42
  int b[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; // 4  5  6    4  5  6    42  81  96
  int c[3][3];                             // 7  8  9    7  8  9   102 126 150

  int d[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};   //  1  2  3      1  2    22 28
  int e[3][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};  //  4  5  6  x   3  4  = 49 64
  int f[2][2];                        //               5  6

  mat_mul_v( 3, 3, a, 3, 3, b, 3, 3, c );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
      printf( "%4d ", c[i][j] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
  }

  putchar( '\n' );

  mat_mul_v( 2, 3, d, 3, 2, e, 2, 2, f );
  
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  {
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
    {
      printf( "%4d ", f[i][j] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
  30   36   42 
  66   81   96 
 102  126  150 

  22   28 
  49   64
```

---

1. And *only* for function parameter declarations - for regular declarations, they mean very different things.

Comment: How would calling the function with, e.g., `&a[0][0]` and iterating through 9 array members be fine? There is an example in [Annex J.2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) that seems to point out that exactly this is UB: "_An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5])._" [The consensus here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290956/one-dimensional-access-to-a-multidimensional-array-is-it-well-defined-behaviour) seems to be that you can't do this.