# How can I give a 2D array from a function to my main function?

Tags: arrays, c

I have a 2D array in the function **arrayConstruction** and I want to give it to the main function to use it there, it works but the values retrieved there are totally inconsistent.
Bellow is what I tried to do so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void arrayConstruction(int nb_row, char** result, int (*givenArr)[2]){

    const char * separator = " ";
    char * strToken;
    char *outt;
    char *end;

    /* 1D array */
    int arrBuf[nb_row*2];
    /* 2D array */
    int (*myArr)[2] = (int(*)[2])arrBuf;
    int i;
    outt = strdup(*result);
    /* Store numbers as 1D array */
    strToken = strtok ( outt, separator );
    for (i = 0; i < nb_row*2 && strToken != NULL ; i++) {
        arrBuf[i] = (int)strtol(strToken, &end, 10);
        strToken = strtok ( NULL, separator);
    }

    givenArr = myArr;


}



int main(int argc, char **argv) 

{

char *result = 
" 2 1\n\
  3 2\n\
  5 2\n\
  5 4\n\
  6 1\n\
  6 2\n\
  7 1\n\
  7 3\n\
  7 4\n\
  8 1\n\
";


int nb_rows = 10;
int emptyArr[][2] ={0};
arrayConstruction(nb_rows, &result, emptyArr);


int i;
  for (i = 0; i < nb_rows; i++) {
    printf("%d---%d\n", emptyArr[i][0], emptyArr[i][1]);
}

}
```

I tried to access it creating a pointer to the array but it's not the right values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
givenArr = myArr;
```

in the function `arrayConstruction` will only change the value of the local variable `givenArr`, which is a pointer. It will not change the original array `emptyArr` in any way, so that the function `main` has no access to the new value.

Even if the function `main` did somehow get access to the new value, this value would be useless to `main`, because the value is a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), for the following reason:

The expression `myArr` is a pointer to the first element of the array `arrBuf`, i.e. `&arrBuf[0]`. However, the entire array `arrBuf` will cease to exist as soon as the function `arrayConstruction` returns, because it is a local array with automatic [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime). Therefore, as soon as the function returns, the pointer will point to a non-existant object, so the pointer is useless.

For this reason, it does not make sense to store the data in an array that is local to the function `arrayConstruction`. It is more meaningful for the array to be declared inside the function `main`, so that its lifetime is as long as the function `main`.

In your function `main`, you are using a 2D array, but in the function `arrayConstruction`, you are using both a 2D array and a 1D array. Since attempting to access a 2D array as a 1D array [is not allowed in plain ISO C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290956/12149471) (although it works on most platforms), it would be better to decide whether you want to use a 2D array or a 1D array, and be consistent in your entire program.

Here is a working example which uses a 1D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void arrayConstruction( int *nb_elements, int givenArr[], char *input )
{
    const char * separator = " ";
    char * strToken;
    char *outt;
    int i;

    outt = strdup( input );

    strToken = strtok ( outt, separator );

    for ( i = 0; i < *nb_elements && strToken != NULL; i++ )
    {
        givenArr[i] = strtol( strToken, NULL, 10 );
        strToken = strtok ( NULL, separator);
    }

    free( outt );

    *nb_elements = i;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *input =
        " 2 1\n"
        " 3 2\n"
        " 5 2\n"
        " 5 4\n"
        " 6 1\n"
        " 6 2\n"
        " 7 1\n"
        " 7 3\n"
        " 7 4\n"
        " 8 1\n"
    ;

    int arr[20] = {0};
    int nb_elements = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    arrayConstruction( &nb_elements, arr, input );

    for ( int i = 0; i < nb_elements / 2; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d---%d\n", arr[i*2+0], arr[i*2+1] );
    }
}
```

Please note that I am calling `free` after using `strdup`, which you did not do in your code, which caused a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

This program has the following output:

```
2---1
3---2
5---2
5---4
6---1
6---2
7---1
7---3
7---4
8---1
```

Here is a working example which uses a 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void arrayConstruction( int *nb_rows, int givenArr[][2], char *input )
{
    const char * separator = " ";
    char * strToken;
    char *outt;
    int i;

    outt = strdup( input );

    strToken = strtok ( outt, separator );

    for ( i = 0; i < *nb_rows && strToken != NULL; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 2 && strToken != NULL; j++ )
        {
            givenArr[i][j] = strtol( strToken, NULL, 10 );
            strToken = strtok( NULL, separator);
        }
    }

    free( outt );

    *nb_rows = i;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *input =
        " 2 1\n"
        " 3 2\n"
        " 5 2\n"
        " 5 4\n"
        " 6 1\n"
        " 6 2\n"
        " 7 1\n"
        " 7 3\n"
        " 7 4\n"
        " 8 1\n"
    ;

    int arr[10][2] = {0};
    int nb_rows = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    arrayConstruction( &nb_rows, arr, input );

    for ( int i = 0; i < nb_rows; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d---%d\n", arr[i][0], arr[i][1] );
    }
}
```

This program has the same output as the other one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations. Is there a way to reproduce that with a 2D array ? I ask because another function in my program is waiting for _arr_ to be a 2D array

Comment: This function I am talking about, has as parameter a **int arr[][2]**

Comment: @ADL92: I have now added a second solution which uses a 2D array everywhere.