# Is it possible to use std::fill with a 2d C-style array?

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have: `unsigned char my2darray[A][B];`

Is it possible to use `std::fill` to set all values of the 2d array to a non-0 value?

I know a vector can be used but this is performance critical code and I can't afford dynamic allocations. Unfortunately, no C++11 is allowed.

Currently used in the code is `memset(my2darray, 0x12, sizeof(my2darray));` but I want to replace all `memset` with `std::fill` if possible, as the type of the array could become a class in future.

Answers which work for any type, not just chars, appreciated.

Comment: How about `std::array`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen [not pre-c++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: note that the current memset will fill the array with `2 071 690 107` (when the my2darray was of `int`)

Comment: @Erbureth Yes, all the more reason not to use it!!! Actually the array in my code is bytes. I just changed it to int for the example. I edited it to char.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because a 2d array is still a sequence of elements that are allocated as a contiguous block of memory.

```
    std::fill (
      &my2darray[0][0],
      &my2darray[0][0] + sizeof(my2darray) / sizeof(my2darray[0][0]),
      none_zero_value);
```

Comment: @WhozCraig It looks the same as the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948290/whats-the-safe-way-to-fill-multidimensional-array-using-stdfill

Comment: @NeilKirk the linked answer is `char`.`sizeof()` works in that example. I should be `&my2darray[0][0]+ A*B` for this question, or `sizeof(my2darray)/sizeof(my2darray[0][0]), the choice is yours. I prefer the former in case `my2darray` is actually `Type (*)[B]` instead of fixed.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think it should be a division;)

Comment: @EricZ  division works correctly when the array is fixed. It will not when the array is only available via row-pointer, thus why I prefer the simpler math, which works in both cases.

Comment: @WhozCraig If `my2darray` is a raw pointer, `&my2darray[0][0]` is a syntax error.

Comment: @EricZ Who said anything about a *raw* pointer? See my comment. I said `Type (*)[B]`; a **row** pointer.

Comment: @WhozCraig `my2darray` is an array not a row pointer. It just decays to it in some cases.

Comment: @EricZ exactly. It is those "some cases" where `sizeof()` division will *not* work, but row*col will. Ex: pass the array to a function where the formal parameter is `Type (*arr)[B]`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sure, that's true.

Answer (score 4):

If [std::fill_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) is an option for you and you don't want to handle sizeof operations on your array, you could use the following:

```
std::fill_n(*my2darray,A*B,my_val)
```

Comment: why `*my2darray` ? shouldnt it be just `my2darray` ?

Comment: ... not it should not ;) However, worth mentioning that this is different for a 2d array as compared to 1d