# Why can't we use std::fill() the same way for 1D and 2D arrays?

Tags: c++

I have seen that if we have a 1D array int A[10], then to fill it with an arbitrary value, say 0, we use 
`std::fill(A, A+10, 0)`

For a 2D array B[10][10], we fill it with 0 as: 
`std::fill(&B[0][0], &B[0][0] + sizeof(B), 0`

However, I can't understand why we can not fill the 1D array A as: 
`std::fill(&A[0], &A[0] + sizeof(A), 0`

Can someone explain this?

Comment: `sizeof(A)` returns the number of bytes, not the number of items.  The `std::fill` function wants the number of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sizeof(T)` returns the number of bytes of type `T`.  It does not return the number of items if `T` is an array type (if you discount `T[0]` being a `char` type).

For the number of items in an array, it would be `sizeof(T) / sizeof(T[0])`, so the `fill` function would be this:

```
std::fill(&A[0], &A[0] + sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]), 0)
```

Comment: What happens in case of the 2D array?

Comment: You have the same error in your question for the 2D array.  The same solution applies there too.

Comment: According to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3948314/2647199), the command for filling the 2D array should work fine.

Comment: Look at my answer.  See where I say "discounting T being a `char` type"?  The answer you linked to only works if the type is `char`.  If the `sizeof(T[0]) > 1`  then you must do as my answer states.  My answer even works if the type is `char`, so you don't lose anything if you use it.

Comment: I edited my answer to emphasize the point that if `T[0]` is not a char type, the number of items in an array can be derived by dividing the array size (in bytes) by the size of each element (in bytes).