# How do I reinitialize a multidimensional array efficiently in Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, multidimensional-array

In Qt, I have a 3-D int-array (say `ID[x][y][z]`) which I need to set back to 0 during computation.

Is there an efficient way to do it without using a loop?

I need the reinitialization because I am running a specific algorithm with a simple cost-function to get an estimation for the following more detailed computation, and I want to use the same data structure. Simply overwriting the array is not an option, because the algorithm reads and checks entries before writing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sooner or later there's going to be a loop, but you can delegate it to another and more optimized function.

Also, if the "3D array" is really an array of arrays of arrays of some basic type (like `int` or `char`), then all the memory is contiguous so you can use a single function call to clear *all* of the memory in one single call.

Now which function to use; In C++ there are basically two functions you can use: The old C [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) function, and the C++ [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) function. Both should work fine, with proper casting and size, to set all of the data to a specific value.

Comment: So in my case, I would use memset(&ID[0][0][0], 0, sizeof(ID))?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood it will (almost) always be a loop. Don't worry, a loop without branches is quite efficient.

If you go for more readable, you can use a function like `memset` or `std::fill` which hides the loop.

Have a look at the answers to this question: [What's the safe way to fill multidimensional array using std::fill?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3948290)

Answer (score 0):

The users @JoachimPileborg and @GeorgSchölly have already explained in their answers which functions can be used to reinitialize an array. However, I'd like to add some sample code and explain a difference between `std::fill()` and `memset()`.

I assume that you want to (re)initialize your array with 0. In this case you can do it as shown in the following code:

```
#include <xutility>  // For std::fill().

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int x = 2;
    const int y = 3;
    const int z = 5;
    const int arraySize = x * y * z;

    // Initialize array with 0.
    int ID[x][y][z] = {};

    // Use the array...

    // Either reinitialize array with 0 using std::fill()...
    std::fill(&ID[0][0][0], &ID[0][0][0] + arraySize, 0);

    // ...or reinitialize array with 0 using memset().
    memset(&ID[0][0][0], 0, sizeof(ID));

    // Reuse the array...

    return 0;
}
```

However, if you want to initialize your array with another value (for example, 1), then you have to be aware of a crucial difference between `std::fill()` and `memset()`: The function `std::fill()` sets each element of your array to the specified value. The function `memset()`, in contrast, sets each byte your array to the specified value. This is why `memset()` takes the array size as number of bytes (`sizeof(ID)`).

If you initialize your array with 0, this difference doesn't cause a problem.
But, if you want to initialize each element of your array with a non-zero value, then you have to use `std::fill()`, because `memset()` will yield the wrong result.

Let's assume you want to set all elements of your array to 1, then the following line of code will yield the expected result:

```
std::fill(&ID[0][0][0], &ID[0][0][0] + arraySize, 1);
```

However, if you use `memset()` in the following way, then you get a different result:

```
memset(&ID[0][0][0], 1, sizeof(ID));
```

As explained above, this line of code sets every byte to 1. Therefore, each integer element of your array will be set to 16843009, because this equals the hexadecimal value 0x01010101.